# CSS displaying elements when thumbnails are hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am attempting to display images when the corresponding thumbnail is hover over using only css and am having trouble with the logic and don't know if it is even possible. i can do it in javascript if absolutely necessary. 
Here is my latest attempt.

```
<div id='img-container' class='grd12'>

    <img id='img1' class='slide-images' src='images/10086115704_15ab56a165_o.jpg' alt='1'>
    <img id='img2' class='slide-images' src='images/9917938624_0a8778f8b1_o.jpg' alt='2'>
    <img id='img3' class='slide-images' src='images/PIA18847.jpg' alt='3'>
    <img id='img4' class='slide-images' src='images/sun-large.jpg' alt='4'>

</div>
<!-- <div class='grd3 thumbnail'>-->
     <img id='thumb1' class='grd3 thumbnail' src='images/10086115704_e36e457d2b_q.jpg' alt='##'>
<!-- </div>-->
<!-- <div class='grd3 thumbnail'>-->
     <img id='thumb2' class='grd3 thumbnail' src='images/9917938624_1ed12deaa2_q.jpg' alt='##'>
<!-- </div>
<div class='grd3 thumbnail'>-->
    <img id='thumb3' class='grd3 thumbnail' src='images/PIA18847.jpg' alt='##'>
<!--</div>
<div class='grd3 thumbnail'>-->
   <img id='thumb4' class='grd3 thumbnail' src='images/sun-large.jpg' alt='##'>
<!--</div>-->
```

And the CSS

```
#img-container{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:950px;
}
.slide-images{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
 }
 .thumbnail > img{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display: inherit;
}
img#thumb4:hover ~ #img4>#image4{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Is that your entire CSS? If I understand correctly, there should be a relationship between each thumbnail and each image, so why are you hiding image 4 when you hover over imagethumb 1?

Comment: yes there should be a relationship but i just put it in like that as proof of concept or testing. it dosn't make a differance i changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is possible using CSS alone, however it is not very scaleable and it might end up being easier and more appropriate to use Javascript for this. For example:

```
img#thumb1:hover ~ #img4>#image4{
    display:none;
}
```

Your selector here is incorrect. The general sibling selector selects only elements *after* the first match. In this case, your image thumb is *after* your image, but this selector is looking for an image *after* an image thumb. This is the opposite of what you have. There is no 'sibling before' selector in CSS.

An easier solution, rather than fiddling around with CSS selectors, would just be to bind each thumbnail to a click event that changes the source of a single image tag each time (or alternatively, scrolls across/fades, whatever animation you're looking for). This way, you save on markup, don't need to worry about positioning as much, and can dynamically generate the image display.

For example, to get the ID of an image, you could bind a click event to each thumbnail and then grab the ID of the image which could stored in a `data` attribute:

```
$('.thumbnail').on('hover', function() {
    var activeImg = $(this).data('imgid');
    // From here, set the main image to have the associated image source
}
```

Comment: thank you. javascript it is then however it has to be on mouse over .

Comment: @Lonergan6275 Edited for mouseover instead of click. Be careful of the difference between `hover` and `mouseover`, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible to achieve with just CSS. The layout of your HTML is what needs to change. In this example:

- Each thumbnail and full-size image is placed inside a div container
- The full-size image is hidden with `opacity: 0;`
- When the div container is hovered, the full-size image is given `opacity: 1` and will fade-in thanks to the transition
- `z-index: 1` keeps the full-size images above the thumbnails

### Full Example

```css
.item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
.fullsize {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.item:hover .fullsize {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

  <img class="fullsize" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-600-600-9.jpg" />
  <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="item">

  <img class="fullsize" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-600-600-9.jpg" />
  <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="item">

  <img class="fullsize" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-600-600-9.jpg" />
  <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="item">

  <img class="fullsize" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-600-600-9.jpg" />
  <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="item">

  <img class="fullsize" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-600-600-9.jpg" />
  <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="item">

  <img class="fullsize" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-600-600-9.jpg" />
  <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" />
</div>
```